# WPF Collapsing VS Rebinding

Tags: wpf, performance, rendering

I have the folowing code which I am able to refactor:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type data:FieldMapping}"
                          ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=FieldMappingItems}">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid"  >
        <Grid.ToolTip >
            <TextBlock Name="Tt" Text="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"/>
        </Grid.ToolTip>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock   Name="Error" Margin="0,0,5,0"  TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.Foreground="Red"  Visibility="Collapsed" Text="!"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
            <Image Source="../../icons\column.png" Name="Image"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\Connect.png" Name="SourceImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\Service.png" Name="AttritubeImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\table.png" Name="SearchImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\surrogateKey.png" Name="TargetImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\Key16.png" Name="PrimayKeyImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\tempTable.png" Name="TempTableImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\Component16.png" Name="SPImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\DatabaseSelectCellSecure16.png" Name="RootImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\Console16.png" Name="ScriptImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Image Source="../../icons\CodeWindowSelect16.png" Name="ProgramImage" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="tb"  Margin="2,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=FieldName}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="tbSource" Margin="2,0,0,0"  Visibility="Collapsed"  Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=FullNodePath}"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>               
        <MultiDataTrigger >
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Published}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FieldMappingType}" Value="TempTable"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="MainGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPrimaryKey}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="PrimayKeyImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="SourceImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="TargetImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="RootImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FieldMappingType}" Value="Table">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="SourceImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="PrimayKeyImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="TargetImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="RootImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FieldMappingType}" Value="TempTable">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="SourceImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="PrimayKeyImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="TempTableImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="RootImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <!--<Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0"/>-->
        </DataTrigger>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

As you can see there are lots of images that are collapsed and then, depending on the type that the object is, the desired image is displayed.

I appreciate that this is a mess and I have refactored it in the following manner:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
                <Grid.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Name="Tt" Text="{Binding Path=ToolTip}" />
                </Grid.ToolTip>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock  x:Name="Error" Margin="0,0,5,0"  TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.Foreground="Red"  Visibility="{Binding Path=Warning, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}" Text="!"/>
                    <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="../../icons\column.png" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=FieldName}" />
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Published}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FieldMappingType}" Value="TempTable" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="MainGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPrimaryKey}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Source" Value="../../Icons/Key16.png" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FieldMappingType}" Value="TempTable">
                    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Source" Value="../../Icons/tempTable.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
```

Although my refactoring is easier to digest and more succint, I was wondering if I am getting better performance through changing the binding of a single image instead of toggling the visibility of multiple one.

Answer (score 0):

It's always more performant to collapse/show rather than change bindings. If the application is really struggling with speed, this is an easy win.

The reason is that when bindings are changed, behind the scenes WPF has to regenerate the entire visual tree. And this is slow. If WPF is collapsing/showing parts of the visual tree, it has some efficient optimizations to make this operation blindingly fast.

The irony is that changing bindings intuitively appeals to programmers, and the C# is usually easier to read and more elegant.

## Update

This rule only applies if you are destroying/creating huge visual trees. If your app is noticably slow, then consider this as an optimization, otherwise avoid as its usually more work to program.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up because this seems very counter intuitive.

Comment: No docs, this is based on experience. First draft of app froze for 3 seconds every time we switched tabs, it was pretty much unusuable. Second draft used hide/show rather than swapping ViewModels and it was instantaneous.

Comment: In the scenario you describe, this seems like a reasonable thing to expect. I wonder if the objects will be stored in memory then? I would expect that they are if you are seeing instantaneous response on a tab switch. As these are all node in a tree view and I can have very many node. I don't want to allocate so much memory as their state doesn't change very often.